# Can I calculate a 95% confidence interval with 20 samples of a measure?

Tags: confidence-interval, auc

I am conducting a experiment that takes lots of time, and I want to report 95% CI of area under the curve (AUC) measures, is it possible to calculate this stat with only 20 samples?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in principle that is possible. Depending on the variability the CI may be so wide that it hardly tells you anything. You probably want to check how precise an answer you need.

Answer (score 1):

The confidence interval depends on the distribution of these measurments,  just compute it on your sample and see whether it gives you a bound which is narrow enough for you.